# Unable to shoot an object in Unity game. Error-ArgumentException: The Object you want to instantiate is null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I'm making a Shooting game for VR in Unity and I'm unable to shoot the object. Everytime I point the object, it throws this error. I tried other posts with same error but they does not answer my problem.

ERROR-
ArgumentException: The Object you want to instantiate is null.
UnityEngine.Object.CheckNullArgument (System.Object arg, System.String message) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEngineObject.cs:239)
UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate (UnityEngine.Object original) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEngineObject.cs:176)
playerScript+c__Iterator0.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/playerScript.cs:30)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (IEnumerator enumerator, IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Coroutines.cs:17)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(String)
playerScript:Update() (at Assets/Scripts/playerScript.cs:61)

I'm attaching an image for better understanding of the scene. The yellow cubes are the Shooting Object.
[image]

Here's the code I'm using-

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class playerScript : MonoBehaviour {

```
//declare GameObjects and create isShooting boolean.
private GameObject gun;
private GameObject spawnPoint;
private bool isShooting;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    //only needed for IOS
    Application.targetFrameRate = 60;

    //create references to gun and bullet spawnPoint objects
    gun = gameObject.transform.GetChild (0).gameObject;
    spawnPoint = gun.transform.GetChild (0).gameObject;

    //set isShooting bool to default of false
    isShooting = false;
}

//Shoot function is IEnumerator so we can delay for seconds
IEnumerator Shoot() {
    //set is shooting to true so we can't shoot continuosly
    isShooting = true;
    //instantiate the bullet
    GameObject bullet = Instantiate(Resources.Load("bullet", typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
    //Get the bullet's rigid body component and set its position and rotation equal to that of the spawnPoint
    Rigidbody rb = bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    bullet.transform.rotation = spawnPoint.transform.rotation;
    bullet.transform.position = spawnPoint.transform.position;
    //add force to the bullet in the direction of the spawnPoint's forward vector
    rb.AddForce(spawnPoint.transform.forward * 500f);
    //play the gun shot sound and gun animation
    GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play ();
    gun.GetComponent<Animation>().Play ();
    //destroy the bullet after 1 second
    Destroy (bullet, 1);
    //wait for 1 second and set isShooting to false so we can shoot again
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (1f);
    isShooting = false;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    //declare a new RayCastHit
    RaycastHit hit;
    //draw the ray for debuging purposes (will only show up in scene view)
    Debug.DrawRay(spawnPoint.transform.position, spawnPoint.transform.forward, Color.green);

    //cast a ray from the spawnpoint in the direction of its forward vector
    if (Physics.Raycast(spawnPoint.transform.position, spawnPoint.transform.forward, out hit, 100)){

        //if the raycast hits any game object where its name contains "zombie" and we aren't already shooting we will start the shooting coroutine
        if (hit.collider.name.Contains("Shooting Object")) {
            if (!isShooting) {
                StartCoroutine ("Shoot");
            }

        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Sure you got your bullet in your Assets/Resources folder ?

Comment: @TanguyB Yes.. its there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line

```
GameObject bullet = Instantiate(Resources.Load("bullet", typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
```

It can't find the resource "bullet."  Make sure you've deployed it into the [right folder](https://itch.io/t/57360/solved-argumentexception-the-object-you-want-to-instantiate-is-null).

Comment: Thanks.. That was the problem.. I used different names in assets folder and the Script.