# Unity Class Instantiate C#

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, instantiation

Working on an assignment and this is one of the examples of code that I'm trying to work with in my code.

```
GameObject prefabRocks;
GameObject rocks = Instantiate(prefabRocks) as GameObject;
```

I get an error every time this code runs in Unity.

Error Is:
UnassignedReferenceException: The variable prefabRocks of Class1 has not been assigned. You probably need to assign the prefabRocks variable of the Class1 script in the inspector.

Can someone help me understand what exactly this code does?

It would help if you can also point me to some reading I can do to understand this weird way of instantiating classes and methods.

Comment: This is not a `weird way of instantiating classes and methods` but the method to use when you want to Instantiate a prefab object into the current Scene. As the exception says your `prefabsRocks` is not assigned (`null`)  and therefore can't be Instantiated. Btw you don't need that `as GameObject`. Please reed [Unity Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to shoot an object in Unity game. Error-ArgumentException: The Object you want to instantiate is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41852713/unable-to-shoot-an-object-in-unity-game-error-argumentexception-the-object-you)

Answer (score 1):

This `prefabRocks` variable of yours is unassigned. There is nothing inside it and you would have to initialise it with something. You can either load in a prefab from the Resource folder in `Start()` or `Awake()` or you can make it a public variable and assign to the variable by dragging and dropping the prefab from the Project tab into the slot here

[image]